# C# console app net 2.0 How to get actual remaining time of another process running?

Tags: c#, mongodb-csharp-2.0, icsharpcode

i have a c# console program .Im using .net 2.0 . Im launching an exe from my console program. That exe shows progress bar on taskbar.

Here i want to read progress percentage from that exe and want to display (1% 2% 3% etc) on my console app program.

(i dont want to display whole output of that exe into my program. i also did test of setting following code but it shows all output of that exe i only want to display percentage )

Is this possible using .net 2.0 ?

im beginner in c#

i have following working code

```
string fullName = "A.exe" ;
      Process p1 = new Process();
      p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
      p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
      p1.StartInfo.FileName = fullName;
      p1.Start(); 
      p1.WaitForExit();
```

[C# console application display remaining time or percentage from another running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991595/c-sharp-console-application-display-remaining-time-or-percentage-from-another-ru/70993517?noredirect=1#comment125552630_70993517)

Comment: How is this any different from your previous question? Do not report the same question a second time just because the question did not get a satisfactory answer, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# console application display remaining time or percentage from another running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991595/c-sharp-console-application-display-remaining-time-or-percentage-from-another-ru)

Comment: @JonasH : that code doesn't show any output on console app

Comment: @JonasH : i can see the taskbar progressbar over an icon on Taskbar. Is there any way to catch that progress and print it on my console app?